# How to ignore row which contain null in specific column in talend?

Tags: talend

My talend job process is:

- Read excel file
- Insert Row in Table.

But I want to ignore row which contain NULL for specific column.
Is there any way to ignore row which contain NULL for specific column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter in a tMap to filter out null columns :

```
tFileInputExcel -- tMap -- tDB..
```

in the tMap output filter, you can use the expression :

```
row.Column != null
```

For the sake of completion, as mentioned by alex, you can also check for empty string:

```
row.Column != null && !row.Column.trim().isEmpty()
```

I've added a trim, in case the string contains only whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

If the imported field is of String type, I have found when using Excel to use the following in the filter:

!Relational.ISNULL(row.Column) &&
row.Column.length() > 0

As Excel and Talend sometimes have a different understanding of what NULL is in a given field.